# Stenciljs autocomplete the unit testing files when the tsx files are changed

Tags: stenciljs

Is there a way to autocomplete the `.spec.tsx` file so that it matches the changes made in the `.tsx` file or every time it has to be done by hand. To be more precise, I would like to autocomplete `expect(page.root).toEqualHtml(RIGHT_HERE)`.

Here is an example:

```
import { newSpecPage } from '@stencil/core/testing';
import { MyComp} from './mapc-events';

describe('my-component-name', () => {
  it('renders', async () => {
    const page = await newSpecPage({
      components: [MyComp],
      html: `<my-component></my-component>`,
      autoApplyChanges: true
    });
    expect(page.root).toEqualHtml(`
      <my-component>
        <mock:shadow-root>
          <slot></slot>
        </mock:shadow-root>
      </my-component>
    `);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not possible at this time, as `toEqualHtml` accepts a string argument (I.E. it's just as acceptable to TypeScript's type checker to pass it 'HelloWorld' or any other invalid HTML). There's no great way for a development environment to recognize a change in the TSX of a stencil component and reflect that properly in the string provided to `toEqualHtml`

Comment: Thank you for information! I will select your answer as the correct one, but keep in mind this might change in the future. Cheers!